# Library structure in C++

Tags: c++

Hello i've been programming in cpp for a few years now, and over time all my functions, classes and such kept being reused. So instead of copy pasting the code into each file, i thought to myself "why not make a c++ library", and so i tried making one. The problem is i have no experience at all in doing this. And after many hours of try and error i came up with a somewhat of a solution but i cannot shake the feeling that its not the correct way. I'd like some professional help to how a proper library is structured.

What i want to create is a library which has the subcategories:
-Core (for core functions)
-SFML (for the sfml functions with sfml library included eg #include <sfml>).
Variables and functions of which i'd be able to use in my code via eg. Test::Core::Constants::const_PI

and i want to future proof this code, so when if i ever need any additional sub categories to each of these, it would be easy to implement eg:

```
-Core
    -Constants
-SFML
    -Network
    -Graphics
    -Window
```

What my code looks like right now is nested classes in different files working together to make it look nice and neat:

[image]

Where the main header is Brabbadon.hpp, which leads to the cpp file of each folder with the same name, which then leads to the seperate classes.
The all files can be found [here](https://github.com/dragonblade767/libraryStackOverflow)

And as a second part to my question i want to ask how i can divide a nested class into multiple hpp and cpp files so that there wouldnt be any multiple redefinition errors. Example of said nested class:

```cpp
    class A
    {
    public:
    int a = 1;
      class B
      {
      public:
      int b = 3
        class C
        {
        public:
          int c = 4;
        }
        
        class D
        {
        public:
          int d = 5;
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your second part should be it's own question. I believe its a completely unrelated topic to project folder layout.

Comment: The folder layout question would likely be closed as opinion-based. The nested class question, if the classes are nested, they are tightly bound together. It's probably not such a good idea try to break them up.

Comment: For your first question, what exactly have you done and what do you think is the problem with it?

Comment: IMHO, you should offer the "cafeteria plan". Also offer libraries for smaller themes as well as a parent encompassing all the themes.  Be able to offer static and dynamic load libraries.

Comment: Ive added an edit @AlanBirtles to show you. Well the problem is more or less i get multiple redifinitions of same functions multiple times a day, and i dont quite understand why or how the code works or how the #define stuff happens

Comment: @user4581301 im not worried about the layout of the folders in which the files are located in, im asking about the structure of the code inside those files: How to make a library that has functions, classes, variables only accecible inside specific "parts" of the library eg if i wanted to use a TEXT class located in Brabbadon::SFML, id want to use Brabbadon::SFML::TEXT to use it and not have it pop up in just Brabbadon. i want to know what the best way to get that is. is it namespaces, nested classes etc

Comment: The best way is whatever works best for you; both namespaces and nested classes work and it depends entirely on whether you expect some other code to extend what exists within those scopes.  For example, if you use namespaces, then any code that pulls in your library could add its own classes/functions inside `Brabbadon::SFML`.  But if `SFML` isn't a namespace but instead is a class, then that's not possible.

Comment: @Naros Ahhh i seee ok Thank you